# Evaluation of the exponential of a symbolic array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, symbolic-math

I'm trying to evaluate the exponential of a symbolic array. Basically I have a numeric array `a` and a symbolic variable `x` defined. I then defined a function `f` which is equal to the exponential of the multiplication of the two, and tried to evaluate the result for a given value of `x`:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *

#Declaration of variables
a=np.array([1, 2])
x = Symbol('x')  
f=exp(a*x)

#Function evaluation
f=f.subs(x, 1)
print(f.evalf())
```

But the following error happens:

```
AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute '_eval_evalf'
```

It seems that `exp()` function isn't prepared for this type of operations.
I know, at least, that it is possible to compute the exponential of a numeric array using `np.exp()`. How should I do it for the case of a symbolic array?

Comment: Are you looking for a matrix exponential or an elementwise exponential? `np.exp` gives an elementwise exponential, not a matrix exponential.

Comment: Mixing NumPy and SymPy like this doesn't work. Stick to one or the other.

Comment: I'm looking for an elementwise exponential. I think you're right about the second comment, I already changed my mind.

Comment: Hi @ÉlioPereira ! Did you find the answer to this question?

Comment: No, I still don't have any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted you should not mix **numpy** and **sympy**. Instead of `array` you can use `Matrix` from sympy and then use `applyfunc` for the component-wise exponential:

```
import sympy as sp

# Declaration of variables
x = sp.Symbol('x')
a = sp.Matrix([1, 2])
f = (a * x).applyfunc(sp.exp)

# Function evaluation
f = f.subs(x, 1)
print(f.evalf())
```

Running this code I do not get any error. Here's my output:

```
Matrix([[2.71828182845905], [7.38905609893065]])
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it requires one to write an expression for each entry of the array a, which isn't 
convenient if the array a is too lengthy. Hence the initial objective of using directly array a instead of its entries.

Comment: If you show a way to introduce array a in the sp.Matrix, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @ÉlioPereira I updated my answer! Is it what you needed? :) Now you won't have to write `exp` for every element anymore

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. Thank you!